# How to stop mongod after “unkown instance” error

Tags: 14.04, services, mongodb

After running two mongodb instance, I can't stop mongod service. After executing:

```
$ sudo service mongod stop
Stop: Unkown instance
```

I know that this question have been asked but they are looking for how to avoid this error and I am looking for how to actually stop the `mongod` service after getting this error...

Answer (score 0):

You could enter this command on the Terminal:

```
mongo host:port --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()"
```

As you said you have been running 2 Mongo instances, thus they should have had 2 various ports. You should do for both.